# How can I prevent the krampus from appearing?

Tags: dont-starve

As of the latest don't starve update a new mob was introduced called the Krumpus, apparently he appears when you hunt too many animals but I don't quite understand how this works. From what I understand, you get several points of "Niceness" when you start, and they decrease as you do naughty things such as hunt animals.

How does this work? Do you get a certain number of naughty points every day or must you perform some "nice" acts in order to raise the amount by which you can hunt? I find this to be a very large impediment while searching for food, I am restricted to purely carrots and berries and seeds, but without meat you can't really survive for that long

Comment: I ignore the naughty / nice thing and just kill the Krumpus whenever he shows up - he dropped charcoal which was nice of him.

Comment: @Ian since I haven't encountered him yet I can't tell how tough he is or how he behaves, I suppose fighting him is an option but still I'd like to avoid him for full peace.

Comment: His behaviour when I encountered him was: I killed some critters and heard his strange sound. He came running onto my screen heading towards me. This freaked me right out as I hadn't read about him beforehand. I ran back to my camp with him hot on my heels. I moved to the side and he didn't follow me, instead he went straight for my chests. He bashed the chest with his sack and my items popped out, he grabbed some and started to run away. I went after him and killed him. He died in 2 spear hits and struck me once - I was wearing a log suit and didn't appear to lose any health.

Comment: (when he died he dropped all of my items that he'd stolen plus some charcoal) - as far as I can tell he spawns near where you kill the 'trigger' animal, and then he runs for your camp to steal items from your chest. If you spot him you can take him down quite easily.

Comment: I managed to get to day 50 (and running) without having to resort to that much meat. If you have a reliable source of manure you can set up a successful mix of crops and berry bushes that can sustain you without having to kill any little creature. Or you can slay spiders for a living and use the crock pot to make them edible. Infinite possibilities!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the informations you need on the [wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus).

Basically at the start of the game you're given a treshold of 30 Naughtyness.
Every action damaging a "nice" creature subtracts points from this treshold according to the following table:

[image: Have you been a bad boy/girl/robot/thing?]

When you reach 0, one or more Krampii (Krampuses?) will spawn, depending on the days you've survived:

[image: Krampii]

Every **60 seconds** spent not doing naughty actions will increase your threshold by one, so this means that if you try to space out your killings in time, you can safely keep hunting for your meat without fearing to meet Krampus. On the table above the "Treshold" column indicates the maximum naughtiness you can have. It has been put in there because it's supposed to go down the more days you play, but there's still an uncertainty on the exact numbers, hence the interval.

Comment: What is the "Threshold" column on the second table? I understand you start with 30 and you gain 1 every 60 seconds of non-naughtiness, but I guess I don't get how that Threshold relates to both of the other columns in the table. Your threshold will always be at 0 when the krampus spawns, so does that indicate what number you get refreshed to after a spawn? (somewhere in that range).. or is the 50 a maximum you can achieve maybe? It's the same for every row, too, so I'm not sure what it could be really.

Comment: @Peter thanks for pointing that out, I've modified the answer.

Comment: By the time I had posted the question the wiki article was pretty small and didn't bring enough good information, but I see now. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score -6):

just make a world before you go in the world go into world edit located under character selection turn to the second to last page and you can turn him off

Comment: This isn't what OP was looking for. Furthermore, they found a solution a long time ago.